# Return values from BenchmarkTools @benchmark

Tags: julia

I would like to collect information about the return values of functions I'm benchmarking, akin to

```
function foo(x)
    x + 1
end

results = []
@benchmark y = foo(x) setup = (x = 3) teardown = (push!(results, y))
```

> ERROR: UndefVarError: `y` not defined

How do I do this properly? Using side-effects inside `foo` obviously distorts the benchmark.

Comment: `@benchmark y=foo(x) setup=(x = 3; y = 0) teardown=(push!(results, y))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the benchmarked code is run in a local scope by `@benchmark`, and so `y` (in `y = foo(x)`) gets created only as a local variable within that scope. `teardown` runs after the code has finished executing, and doesn't have access to that scope - `y` is out of scope and possibly out of memory by then.

The fix is pretty simple - mark the `y` as a global variable.

```
@benchmark (global y = foo(x)) setup = (x = 3) teardown = (push!(results, y))
```

Comment: Although I went with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272195/return-values-from-benchmarktools-benchmark/76275259#76275259, due to better programming practices, this answer explains the problem and solves it adequately.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is to use a reference:

```
y2 = Ref{Int}()
@benchmark y2[] = foo(x) setup = (x = 3) teardown = (push!(results, y2[]))
```

This will get all data collected in the `results` vector.

Note this assumed the type for y2.
If you do not know what expect you could use `y2 = Ref{Any}()` instead.